What is the purpose of the "UPLUS()" function in Google Sheets?
Google Sheets defines several unary functions and operators, and while most of them seem to have a purpose, UPLUS's help article says

Returns a specified number, unchanged.

From my experimentation, it seems to leave strings and booleans in their original types as well, and I can't figure out what utility this function would have.
See this example spreadsheet for some of the ways in which it seems to have no effect

What is your purpose to use this function?

I can't know if I have a purpose for it until I know what it does

It seems to have the same purpose (or lack thereof) as the unary + operator in other programming languages. Perhaps someone wanted to ensure that every algebraic expression could be written in a functional form, and therefore every operator needed a functional equivalent?

Except in other programming languages unary plus does have a use in that it can promote to a larger integer type, but this isn't relevant for google sheets, which doesn't deal with types at that level

@Lewis see the example spreadsheet I added, it seems to have no effect that isn't performed automatically on other data types

https://www.devgem.io/posts/understanding-the-uplus-function-in-google-sheets-a-closer-look This article seems AI generated from your  question and the answer below. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/

There are use cases for a function that returns its parameter unchanged, for example when currying.
Strictly speaking, uplus() doesn't always return references and arrays unchanged.  Like many other functions, it only returns the first element, unless evaluated in an array formula context.
One simple use  case is to get the first element in an array, like this:
=uplus(filter(A2:A5, len(A2:A5)))

...or, since the uplus() function corresponds to the unary + operator, like this:
=+filter(A2:A5, len(A2:A5))

There are nowadays many ways to accomplish the same, such as single(), but back in the day the unary + was the easiest way, and it's still used a lot.

This article https://www.devgem.io/posts/understanding-the-uplus-function-in-google-sheets-a-closer-look seems AI generated from your answer.

@TheMaster thanks. Interesting. I can see how the next AI in the chain will use that article as its source, adding more prattle each step, ad infinitum. Stack Overflow content is CC BY-SA, but Devgem is arrogant enough to claim copyright on their page.

It seems "AI" is just a way to get around copyright limitations. In any case, I highly doubt SO would/can do anything about this, as they are not the copyright owner of content and have little incentive to interfere. There are still other options: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178 (like reporting spam to Google)
